# PLSQL pass parameter to .sql file from .shl script

Tags: sql, shell, plsql

I am trying to run a shell script with values and pass those values into a .sql file which will call my plsql procedures with these values. I've tried a lot with no luck.

What I have now:

```
shl script: RunSql $SQL_PATH/update_load_status.sql 'N'
sql script: execute dbms_output.put_line('&1'); (based on other code in system - (&1) gives a bind var not declared)
```

Will multiple values work in a similar manner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the DEFINE keyword to capture the arguments passed to a shell script

```
define first_arg=&1
define second_arg=&2

BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('&first_arg');
    dbms_output.put_line('&second_arg');
END;
/
```